# How to change data in `App` component in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, router

I have `App` component in Vue that extends `Login` component using `<router-view>`. I want to change some data in `App` component whenever I click a button in my `Login` component. Is that possible in Vue?

Comment: Yes it is possible.   Can you show us some of your existing code to work with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are sharing data between components, you might want to consider using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html).

> Vuex is a state management pattern + library for Vue.js applications. It serves as a centralized store for all the components in an application, with rules ensuring that the state can only be mutated in a predictable fashion.

Alternatively you can emit a event from child component and listen for it in parent component.

In App.vue template,

```
<router-view @updateParent="handleUpdate"></router-view>
```

In App.vue methods,

```
handleUpdate: function (value) {
    this.parentData = value
}
```

In Login.vue in @click method,

```
onButtonClick: function () {
    this.$emit('updateParent', "value")
}
```